# jquery Select <a> tag which contains specific href in nested div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

how I can select the `<a>` tag containing the `href="www.dummy.ch"` in the following code with `jquery`.

I have to modify the target attribute with `_top` instead of `_blank`.
No ID or class attribute is set in the  tag.

Thanks,
Patric

```html
<div class="QvContent" style="width: 485px; height: 26px; overflow: visible; border-bottom-right-radius: 1px; border-bottom-left-radius: 1px; background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);">
 <div class="QvGrid" style="width: 485px; height: 26px; overflow: hidden; font-family: Tahoma; font-size: 8pt; font-style: normal; font-weight: normal; text-decoration: none; position: relative; cursor: default;" incontainer="false" fixed_cols_left="1">
  <a style="position: absolute;" href="http://www.dummy.ch" target="_blank" unselectable="on">
   <div title="URL " style="left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 389px; height: 13px; text-align: center; color: rgb(54, 54, 54); overflow: hidden; font-style: normal; font-weight: normal; text-decoration: underline; position: absolute; cursor: pointer; background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);">
    <div style="left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 389px; height: 13px; border-left-color: rgba(220, 220, 220, 1); border-left-width: 0px; border-left-style: solid; position: absolute;" unselectable="on"/>
    <div class=" injected" style="padding: 0px 2px; width: 385px; height: 13px;">
     <div title="URL " style="width: 385px; overflow: hidden; white-space: pre; cursor: default; -ms-word-wrap: normal;" unselectable="on">
      <a style="display: inline-block;" href="http://www.axeed.ch" target="_blank" unselectable="on">URL</a>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </a>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: try `$("a[href^='withyour url']")`

Comment: Sounds like homework to me. Why not look up how to grab HTML elements by attribute value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this : You can use **[attribute containing selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/)** of jquery to get all anchor with href value containing www.dummy.ch and change its target value.

```
$("a[href*='www.dummy.ch']").attr("target", "_top");
```

Comment: Thanks I tried with your suggestion but it does not work:

` $(document).ready(function () {
   $( ".QvGrid" ).attr( "title", "Hi I have a new caption" );
   $("a[href*='axeed.ch']").attr("target", "_top");
        })`

I can inject the QvGrid div with a custom title attribut but indeed the <a> injection is not working

Comment: I had to add a timeout in my code till the code was rendered completely and then the injection worked correctly. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

try

```
$("a[href*='www.dummy.ch']").attr("target", "_top");
```

Comment: Should be $('a[href*="dummy.ch"]) to affect subdomains and other protocols. Edit: oh, you added it already.

Comment: @VergilPenkov yeah, after posting I immediately thought that I was missing something :)

Comment: It is not homework! I try to modify a rendered html page and inject a specific <a> tag with a custom target!

Answer (score 0):

If you want the domain, plus subdomains:
`$("a[href*='dummy.ch']").attr("target", "_top");`

If you want the domain without subdomains:
`$("a[href*='//dummy.ch']").attr("target", "_top");`

If you want to target a specific protocol:
`$("a[href^='http://dummy.ch']").attr("target", "_top");` (replace "http") with whatever you want.

The ***=** part suggests that the href attribute contains **dummy.ch**. The **^=** part would mean that the href tag begins with what's inside the quotes.